# How to commit remote files on git pull?

Tags: git, githooks

**The problem:**

There is a php script on my server changing some files in a dir called "example/". This changed files are "uncommitted", ok. So, to bring this changes I need to:

- login in the server
- go to site directory
- set git bare=false
- add and commit all
- set bare=true
- finally git pull the changes to work in local!

This is a very boring work and I would to know if there is a way or script to do it automatic. Maybe the git hooks could help to do this tasks but I can't find anything about this problem.

Or (if exists) some git command to remote update from local.

Sorry my english. ^^

Answer (score 1):

If it's your php script, and/or you have access to change it, you could just edit the script to commit the changes.

Otherwise, depending on your server platform, you could add a cron job (or scheduled task (Windows) etc) and write a new script to periodically commit changes.

As far as I know, git hooks don't apply here because the working directory is just being changed by the php script, which isn't actually a git function.